# Unit testing owin middleware which sets query string

Tags: c#, owin, middleware

I have a owin middleware, which checks for particular value in the query string, and updates another value in query string. I am using Microsoft.OWin.Testing to call this piece of middleware and then make a request. How do I exactly check the query string was changed after I make request.

```
public static void UseInjectQueryString(this IAppBuilder app)
{        
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                 // Some code here
                 if (context.Environment.ContainsKey("owin.RequestQueryString"))
                 {
                      var existingQs = context.Environment["owin.RequestQueryString"];
                      var parser = new UrlParser(existingQs.ToString());
                      parser[Constants.AuthorizeRequest.AcrValues] = newAcrValues;

                      context.Environment.Remove("owin.RequestQueryString");
                      context.Environment["owin.RequestQueryString"] = parser.ToString();
                  }
          }

    await next();
});
```

Unit test :

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SomeTest()
{
    using (var server = TestServer.Create(app =>
                             {                
                                 //.... injecting middleware..
                             }))
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await server.CreateRequest("core/connect/token?client_id=clientStub").GetAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor the middleware so that you can test it outside of the pipeline. For example, you could structure it like this:

```
public static class InjectQueryStringMiddleware
{
    public static void InjectQueryString(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context.Environment.ContainsKey("owin.RequestQueryString"))
        {
            var existingQs = context.Environment["owin.RequestQueryString"];
            var parser = new UrlParser(existingQs.ToString());
            parser[Constants.AuthorizeRequest.AcrValues] = newAcrValues;

            context.Environment.Remove("owin.RequestQueryString");
            context.Environment["owin.RequestQueryString"] = parser.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static void UseInjectQueryString(this IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // some code here
            InjectQueryString(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can test `InjectQueryString` and that it does the right thing to the context, without having to create the entire pipeline.

Comment: This is nice. So here I should just unit test InjectQueryString method by mocking context and and not to use TestServer.Create method to create and instance of the server. Is that correct? If that is the case how do I cover following lines of code app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // some code here
            InjectQueryString(context);
        }

Comment: You don't; unless `// some code here` is actually something worth testing (and then you can lift that out in a similar fashion), that code is so trivial you don't have to (unit) test it. Of course, if this doesn't work, functionality that relies on the query injection stuff will fail later in the pipeline, so an integration test (manual or automatic) of a larger part of your system should easily cover that.